# Verifying Moq method call when used as a base class/interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, assert

I'm trying to verify a method call on a Moq implementing the following interface(s), but it is failing to match the invocation.

My unit test (simplified):

```
[Test]
public void ShouldDeleteComponent()
{
    var mockDao = new Mock<IComponentDataAccess>();

    Target.ComponentDao = mockDao.Object;
    Target.Execute();

    mockDao.Verify(x => x.Delete(It.IsAny<Component>()), Times.Once);
}
```

My mocked object's interfaces:

```
public interface IComponentDataAccess : IDataAccess<Component>
{
    int Delete(Component entity);
}

public interface IDataAccess<T> where T : IEntity
{
    int Delete(T entity);
}
```

Finally, how the code is actually called in the System Under Test:

```
public override void Execute()
{
    DeleteItem(ComponentDao, existingComponent);
}
```

which calls:

```
protected virtual void DeleteItem<T>(IDataAccess<T> dataAccess, T item) where T : IEntity
{
    dataAccess.Delete(item);
}
```

As you can see, the DAO is passed in as its base interface. On verification, it finds the following invocation:

> Performed invocations:
>
> IDataAccess`1.Update(blah.namespace.UserAccount)

When the invocation it's trying to match is:

> IUserAccountDataAccess.Update(blah.namespace.UserAccount)

Is there a way to verify this method call with Moq?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change:

```
mockDao.Verify(x => x.Delete(It.IsAny<Component>()), Times.Once);
```

to:

```
mockDao.As<IDataAccess<Component>>()
       .Verify(x => x.Delete(It.IsAny<Component>()), Times.Once);
```

The `As` method is being in use for adding other types